# Not getting the specific value

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

well i'm trying to **scrape** the value of the availability if a product using bs4 and python so to know if the product is available if the value "En stock" exist else is not. however i'm getting a false even the value "En stock" is true. this my code. thank you for helping me

````
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
soupe = bs(response.content, 'html5lib')
data = []
for element in soupe.find_all("div", class_="content-price"):
        dispo = element.find("div", class_="stock").text
        if dispo == " En stock":
            dispo["available"] = True
        else:
            dispo["available"] = False
 data.append(dispo)
def main():
    url ="https://www.e.leclerc/fp/sun-secure-apres-soleil-hydratant-200ml-3401360167834"
    dispo =  parsing(url)   
    print(disp)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the text for `dispo` can contain extra whitepsace, remove it using `.strip()`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.e.leclerc/fp/sun-secure-apres-soleil-hydratant-200ml-3401360167834"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


for element in soup.find_all("div", class_="content-price"):
    dispo = element.find("div", class_="stock").text
    # check if `dispo` is `None` since calling `.strip()` would raise an error
    if not dispo:
        print("No value found")
        continue

    if dispo.strip() == "En stock":
        print("In stock")
    else:
        print("Not in stock")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to select `<app-product-availability-state>` tag for checking the availability status:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.e.leclerc/fp/sun-secure-apres-soleil-hydratant-200ml-3401360167834"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")

availability = (
    "En stock" in soup.select_one("app-product-availability-state").text
)

if availability:
    print("Item is in stock")
else:
    print("Item is NOT in stock")
```

Prints:

```
Item is in stock
```

Comment: thank you for ur solution app-product-availability-state is an angular tag it can be chaged any time

Comment: @taniiit `BeautifulSoup` doesn't execute javascript, it parses only text. So tag `<app-product-availability-state>` won't change.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    if not soup.select_one('.fas.fa-circle').next_element.strip().startswith('E'):
        print('Item Not Available')
    else:
        print('Item Available')


main('https://www.e.leclerc/fp/sun-secure-apres-soleil-hydratant-200ml-3401360167834')
```

Output:

```
Item Available
```